# PowerMockito whenNew without PrepareForTest

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, testing, powermock

Jacoco does not cover tests using @PrepareForTest(Class.class).

I need to use PowerMockito whenNew method, but it does not work without the PrepareForTest annotation.

Is there any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JaCoCo could work in two mods:

- collecting coverage with java agent
- offline instrumentation

If you'd like to collect coverage from PowerMock test then you should use offline instrumentation.

Here working example for Gradle: https://github.com/SurpSG/jacoco-offline-instrumentation

Comment: Thank you ! Do you have any gradle examples for Java agent as well ?

Comment: [JaCoCo Gradle plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html) uses java agent. All you need is to apply the plugin